# Сортировка товаров на сайте с помощью тега <select> в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hook, jsx

Всем привет, я новичок в **React** и только начинаю понимать азы. Сейчас я создаю сайт магазина одежды для самообучения, имитируя существующий сайт **"spbtusa.ru"**
На данный момент у меня проблема с сортировкой товаров на главной странице. Согласно идее, при выборе типа сортировки пользователь воздействует на атрибут **onChange** тега `<select>`, этим действием  изменяет **State** при помощи функции именения state - *setCurrentSorting*, добавляя в него функцию сортировки. При изменении **State**, список товаров, отображаемых на странице, должен быть отрисован заново.

Тег `<select>` и вызываемая функция изменения состояния - setCurrentSorting, которые я передал в качестве props из родительского компонента (MainContentHeader.jsx)

```
<select onChange={(e) => {
                switch (e.target.value) {
                  case "price:asc":
                    setCurrentSorting(SortPriceAsc);
                    break;
                  case "price:desc":
                    setCurrentSorting(SortPriceDesc);
                    break;
                  case "title:asc":
                    setCurrentSorting(SortTitleAsc);
                    break;
                  case "title:desc":
                    setCurrentSorting(SortTitleDesc);
                    break;
                  case "created:asc":
                    setCurrentSorting(SortCreatedAsc);
                    break;
                  case "created:desc":
                    setCurrentSorting(SortCreatedDesc);
                    break;
                }
              }} className="main-content-header__order">
    <option data-filter-value="" value="">Порядок: по умолчанию</option>
    <option data-filter-value="price:asc" value="price:asc">Цена: по возрастанию</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Простые функции сортировок (MainContentHeader.jsx)

```
function SortPriceDesc(a, b) {
  if (
    parseInt(a.price.replace(/\s/g, "")) > parseInt(b.price.replace(/\s/g, ""))
  )
    return -1;
  else return 1;
}
function SortPriceAsc(a, b) {
  if (
    parseInt(a.price.replace(/\s/g, "")) < parseInt(b.price.replace(/\s/g, ""))
  )
    return -1;
  else return 1;
}
...
```

Родительский компонент, связывающий список продуктов и `<select>` для выбора сортировки (HomePage.jsx)

```
export default function HomePage() {
  const [currentSorting, setCurrentSorting] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <IntroSlider />
      <main className="main-content">
        <MainContentHeader setCurrentSorting={()=>setCurrentSorting} />
        <ProductSection currentTypeOfSorting={currentSorting} />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Дочерний компонент, отображающий список продуктов. Функция loopWithSlice определяет, сколько продуктов мне нужно отобразить первыми из списка. (ProductSection.jsx)

```
const initialCountProducts = 36;
const productsPerСlick = 12;

export default function ProductSection({ currentFuncOfSorting }) {
  const [limitedProductList, setProductsToShow] = useState([]);
  const [next, setNext] = useState(initialCountProducts);
  const [sortProductList, setSortProductList] = useState(productList);

  useEffect(() => {
    let sorted = [...sortProductList.sort(currentFuncOfSorting)];
    setSortProductList(sorted);
    setProductsToShow(sorted.slice(0, initialCountProducts));
  }, [currentFuncOfSorting]);

  const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
    const slicedProduct = sortProductList.slice(start, end);
    setProductsToShow(slicedProduct);
  };

  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    loopWithSlice(next, next + productsPerСlick);
    setNext(next + productsPerСlick);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="product-section">
        {limitedProductList.map((item, index) => (
          <ProductCard key={index} {...item} />
        ))}
      </section>
      {limitedProductList.length < productList.length && (
        <div className="product-section__button">
          <button onClick={handleShowMorePosts}>Загрузить ещё</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно вызвать функцию **loopWithSlice** один раз во время первого рендеринга (как я понял, используя хук *useEffect*), и каждый раз, когда изменяется состояние родительского элемента (тип сортировки), должен изменяться **sortProductList** и **ProductSection** компонент должен быть отрисован повторно. Однако код либо переходит в бесконечный цикл, либо ничего не рендерит повторно..

Я буду рад, если вы, как более опытные, сможете сказать мне, что я делаю не так и почему это не работает. Повторяю, я новичок и еще многого не понял. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [a, setA] = useState()
```

`setA` имеет два синтексиса:

1. setA(значение)
2. setA((предидушее значение) => значение)

когда ты передал в сеттер функцию он подумал что это втарой синтексис и вызвал ее от сюда и проблемы

вот алтернативное решение

```
const getIntegerPrice = (product) => parseInt(product.price.replace(/\s/g, ""));

const sortPriceDesc = (a, b) => {
  const firstPrice = getIntegerPrice(a);
  const secondPrice = getIntegerPrice(b);
  if (firstPrice > secondPrice) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
};

const sortPriceAsc = (a, b) => {
  const firstPrice = getIntegerPrice(a);
  const secondPrice = getIntegerPrice(b);
  if (firstPrice < secondPrice) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
};

const SORTING = {
  "price:asc": {
    key: "price:asc",
    sortingFn: sortPriceAsc,
  },
  "price:desc": {
    key: "price:desc",
    sortingFn: sortPriceDesc,
  },
};

const HomePage = () => {
  const [currentSortingType, setCurrentSortingType] = useState();
  //можно дастать и тут и в ProductSection прабросив туда currentSortingType
  //если пробросить currentSortingType то она и станет зависимостю для useEffect
  //если нет то зависимостю будет currentSortingFn
  const currentSortingFn = SORTING[currentSortingType].sortingFn;
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <MainContentHeader setCurrentSortingType={setCurrentSortingType} />
        {/* <ProductSection currentSortingFn={currentSortingFn} /> */}
        {/* либо */}
        {/* <ProductSection currentSortingType={currentSortingType} /> */}
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

const MainContentHeader = ({ setCurrentSortingType }) => {
  return (
    <select
      onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
        if (value) {
          setCurrentSortingType(value);
        }
      }}
    >
      <option value={SORTING["price:asc"].key}>x</option>
      <option value={SORTING["price:desc"].key}>y</option>
    </select>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Проблема решена.** Надеюсь, я правильно понимаю, в state можно добавлять только функции, которые не принимают аргументы, поэтому мы превращаем функцию сортировки в функцию со стрелкой.

*Если я ошибаюсь, поправьте меня, пожалуйста.*

```
<select
  onChange={(e) => {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "price:asc":
        setSorting(() => SortPriceAsc);
        break;
      case "price:desc":
        setSorting(() => SortPriceDesc);
        break;
      ...
      default:
        setSorting(() => DefaultSortIdAsc);
    }
  }}
  className="main-content-header__order"
>
  <option data-filter-value="" value="">
    Порядок: по умолчанию
  </option>
  <option data-filter-value="price:asc" value="price:asc">
    Цена: по возрастанию
  </option>
  <option data-filter-value="price:desc" value="price:desc">
    Цена: по убыванию
  </option>
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: В сеттер реакта может быть передано либо само значение, либо функция. Скорее всего в первом варианте вы получали в стейт не саму функцию, а результат ее выполнения. А в данном случае вы получили как раз саму фукнцию. Однако это не должно было зацикливать рендер

Comment: нет, ты не правильно понял, можно передать все что душе угодно, одна проблема с тем что ты делаеш так <MainContentHeader setCurrentSorting={()=>setCurrentSorting} />, надо так <MainContentHeader setCurrentSorting={setCurrentSorting} />

Comment: @Armen Вот как раз `setCurrentSorting={setCurrentSorting}` приводит к тому, что вызывается функция как колбэк и в сеттер летит результат ее выполнения(подозреваю, что это undefined)

Comment: @SwaD в верхнем примере вызывается setCurrentSorting(сартировка), но сейчас переданная функция в MainContentHeader нечего не принимает по сути, еще бы MainContentHeader полностю увидеть стало бы понятнее

Comment: @SwaD да сначало и не заметил этот момент.